# What data format/structure is this and how to handle it?

Tags: data-structures

So I have ran into such data format:

```
{
    "i": {
        "hid|15#aid|9305#h|Openjobmetis Varese#a|Germani Basket Brescia#h2|VARESE#a2|BRESCIA#round|1019#nat|ita#hcolors": {
            "bg|851010#g1|920000#g2|ad0b0b#g3|800000#c|"
        },
        "acolors": {
            "bg|037f43#g1|00582d#g2|0fb966#g3|037f43#c|"
        },
        "hp|33#vp|20"
    },
    "idor": 0,
    "jr|1#t": 19,
    "t2": 30,
    "ip|#b": false,
    "v": {
        "h": 0,
        "a": 0,
        "t": 30,
        "h2": 12,
        "a2": 12
    }
}
```

I have never seen such structure and I could not find any sources to explain me this format. Actually I was not even sure how to search it.

So yeah, my question is, what is this data format and how can I handle it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, right after posting this question, I was able to decode this JSON. It seemed like a JSON all along but these pipes were kind of intimidating. This is how I solved it eventually.

```
function jsonDecode(json){
    if(!json) return null;
    json = json.replace(/#/g, '","').replace(/\|/g, '":"').replace(/%/g, '"},{"');
    return JSON.parse(json);
}
```

Great! This question is now answered. Thanks everybody!

Answer (score 2):

Looks like [JSON](https://www.json.org/).

It appears some data was also encoded as pipe-delimited string values in the JSON.